# ThreeJS PathControl rotate around object and change camera position

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to use PathControl to move the camera around a plan. I need to turn the camera to look at a given point somewhere in the plan.  I dont want to use Orbit control because the path that the camera moves needs to be dynamic and is not always a circle. I get that in the render method i need to call camera.lookAt but i cant seem to get the math correct.

Here is an example jsfiddle. Need to update the camera in the render function to always point at the square.

`camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));`

http://jsfiddle.net/jamescharlesworth/2UHYE/

Comment: `PathControls` is a little hard to understand or modify. Consider a different approach: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_splines.html. Click on the animation button.

Comment: Looks cool, but im not seeing how that would allow me to focus on a center object. I really dont have a need to change the y coord and feel like im almost there (see js fiddle).